# How to delete a voice channel the user is in?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Im making a command where a user can create and delete a private voice channel. For the part where i want to add or delete a channel it wants me to add a variable. I need it to delete the voice channel the user is in. Than you in advance

Code:

```
client.command()
async def room(ctx, activity=None, *, member : discord.Member = None):
    if activity == "STREAMING".lower():
        guild = ctx.guild
        user = ctx.author
        await guild.create_voice_channel(f"Streaming Room - {user}")
        await ctx.send("Created streaming room!")
    elif activity == "RECORDING".lower():
        guild = ctx.guild
        user = ctx.author
        channel = await guild.create_voice_channel(f"Recording Room - {user}")
        everyone = ctx.message.author.guild.default_role
        disallow = discord.PermissionOverwrite()
        disallow.read_messages = False
        disallow.send_messages = False
        await channel.set_permissions(everyone, overwrite=disallow)
        await ctx.send("Created recording room!")
    elif activity == 'ADD'.lower():
        await ctx.send(f"{member.mention} has been added to your room")
        allow = discord.PermissionOverwrite()
        allow.connect = True
        allow.speak = True
        await channel.set_permissions(member, overwrite=allow)
    else:
        await ctx.send('Please specify what activity you would like to be doing [streaming, recording]')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## General command for the task:

```py
@client.command()
async def delvc(ctx, member: discord.Member):
    vc = member.voice.channel
    if vc:
        await vc.delete()
        await ctx.send(f"{member.name}'s voice channel - `{vc.name}` - was deleted!")
    else:
        await ctx.send(f"{member.name} isn't in a voice channel at the moment.")
```

---

**References:**

- [`Member.voice`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.voice)
- [`discord.VoiceChannel`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.VoiceChannel)
- [`VoiceChannel.delete()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.VoiceChannel.delete)